# How do I translate an SQL statement to use in an sqlx API call?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

I've been trying to query PostgreSQL [ltree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ltree.html). Here in table `tree`, `path` has type `ltree`.
I could write in psql:

```
SELECT id, path FROM tree WHERE path @ '12345'
```

with no problem.
When I do in sqlx:

```
db.Get(&path, "SELECT id, path FROM tree WHERE path @ '$1'", entryID)
```

it keeps telling `pq: operant syntax error`. Not sure if there's a way to properly escape single quote in the query string. I tried this but still doesn't work:

```
db.Get(&path, `SELECT id, path FROM tree WHERE path @ ''$1''`, entryID)
```

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes in a Go string.

Comment: You sure you got the correct error message in the question? Can't find the word "operant" in neither Go's std lib, nor sqlx, nor postgres source code.

Comment: I believe single quotes around your parameter would make it a string literal, so the value of entryID would not be interpolated into the query. If entryID is an int and you want it to be treated as a string by the query then try using type casting. e.g. `... path @ $1::text`.

Comment: @Adrian @mkopriva you guys are right.  I don't need the single quote in the query string. just the `$1` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I don't need the single quote around $1 at all. This query would work:

```
db.Get(&path, `SELECT id, path FROM tree WHERE path @ $1`, entryID)
```

Comment: Accept your own answer.